# Kivy - Buildozer - нет компиляции в Colab

Tags: apk, buildozer

Пытаюсь сделать в колабе арк файл, но появляется ошибка No module named '_ctypes'

Все необходимое загружено в таком порядке

1. !pip install buildozer
2. !pip install cython==0.29.19
3. !sudo apt-get install -y 
   python3-pip 
   build-essential 
   git 
   python3 
   python3-dev 
   ffmpeg 
   libsdl2-dev 
   libsdl2-image-dev 
   libsdl2-mixer-dev 
   libsdl2-ttf-dev 
   libportmidi-dev 
   libswscale-dev 
   libavformat-dev 
   libavcodec-dev 
   zlib1g-dev
4. !sudo apt-get install -y 
   libgstreamer1.0 
   gstreamer1.0-plugins-base 
   gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
5. !sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
6. !sudo apt-get install build-essential libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 bzip2 libbz2-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev openssl libgdbm-dev libgdbm-compat-dev liblzma-dev libreadline-dev libncursesw5-dev libffi-dev uuid-dev libffi6
7. !apt-get update

Все варианты решения в инете касаются обновления питона и установки libffi
Может есть еще какие наработки?

Answer (score 0):

Нашелся рабочий блокнот Колаба со всеми нужным скриптами для компиляции
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1b9gMzs6XAtxCtahxei4N0fWZk7xiPlVw?usp=sharing